# What browsers is supported by stable Dart 1.1.1?

Tags: dart

What browsers is supported by stable Dart 1.1.1 - where can I find such information or results of tests done on browsers. I want be sure what I can except in future version.

It is not clear for me what mean "major browsers" since it is not clear if it is tested. I plan to use dart since can be nice in doing advanced application.

---

I think only about compatibility of **Dart/JavaScript** - **not interested** in pure Dart in Chromium.

Comment: Are you talking about the Dart code, or the Dart2JS-generated Javascript code?

Comment: Only about code compatible with the most browsers - so it will be JavaScript code. Since now no support for Dart apart Chromium I think - am I right?

Comment: @Diti I want to know at first what browsers support Dart/JavaScript code - since each browser is different. I've already know the pure Dart is not option for web application - it is not answer - chromium is not option to use now.

Comment: @mezoni Not constructive and no matter.

Comment: Is there any product on the market that guarantees some degree of compatibility with several browsers or a fixed time for bug fixes. I believe you that you really want to know, but all in all your question is redundant because it's not possible for anyone to give a reliable anwer.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Dart FAQ](https://www.dartlang.org/support/faq.html#q-what-browsers-do-you-support-as-javascript-compilation-targets):

> Q. What browsers do you support as JavaScript compilation targets?
>
> We’re currently aiming to support the following browsers:
>
> ```
> Internet Explorer, versions 9 and 10.
> Firefox, latest version.
> Chrome, latest version.
> Safari for desktop, version 6.
> ```

Though "We're currently aiming to support" certainly doesn't inspire the same level of confidence that "We support" would.

Comment: Yeah, that is my problem "We're currently aiming to support" == "Not done and we not take risk" - shorter we not take responsibility :)

Comment: Let me cite this - see IE11. See that people not use latest Chrome and FF at all (drill down Chrome FF). http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp that is my problem since can not order to change browser like local administrator.

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering about that as well. Latest 3 versions would be a much safer bet. I assume that there's not much difference, but as you say it would be nice to have a firm guarantee somewhere.

Comment: I think that it can be versions published during last 12 months. Some guarantee gives good foundations.

Answer (score 2):

*It's not really an answer but to long for a comment:*

Dartium is intended for development only.
JavaScript generated from Dart is currently the only supported scenario of Dart for production use.

Dart or more specific the generated JS helps a lot in abstracting browser differences away but there are also still a lot of open issues, some with known workarounds and some without.

I doubt there can or will be a perfect solution even in the future. 
How good or bad someone finds the support of one of the browsers listed in @PixelElephant s answer is mostly based on opinion and/or what features someone wants to use.

If you have issues with some of these browsers, post an issue. Common features are likely to be fixed in the short therm others may take longer (also depending on complexity).

Comment: The problem is that I do not know if problems will be solved in one year or one month - I can not take risk/trust if it undetermined. Dart can be nice since strict type/dynamic both and has better OO model but it is not advantage if it not works on major browsers for sure.

It is need to write some unit test and check it before. I want to use but it must be ready.

Comment: How long will be solved trivial or medium bug in one of major browsers. http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_stats.asp

Comment: IMHO you have three options: try it and find out; believe someones biased opinion; use something else.

Comment: I started nearly a year ago and I'm still trying. IMHO Dart has more advantages than disadvantages - if that is of any help.

Comment: Dart has better syntax than JavaScript and API. It not explain usage in public web project. You can use it in local project without risk if you choose one browser with all advantages.